# Calling long-running service in sync django app

Tags: performance, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I have a Django rest framework application running in sync mode with `gunicorn` using option `--workers=1`. The application has an api method which calls external service over http. That service responds for a long time. So my whole application is blocked untill the response is recieved. What options do I have for application not to be blocked by that service? I considered caching but it is not very usefull as requests are different.

Comment: Why do you need it to be in `sync` mode? And if so, why did you tag your question with [tag:asynchronous]? Consider `gevent` or other [Async Workers](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/install.html#async-workers).